# Best way to store Permutations?

Tags: database, math, storage

I want to know the most efficient way to store all the permutations of the group of numbers between 1 - 100 that reach the sum of 100 - 198.

because I assume it will be quite a large number I wanted to ask what is the best way to store it.

edit:
I noticed my question was not so clear... ill try to make it better -
I have a class "car" which has 2 properties: Grade (int) and Type("Ferari"). I had a code which got all the combos but when i had 29 cars the number of permutations(or combos because someone said permutations might be a misuse of the word) was (2^29 - 1) which is too big for me to calculate effecintly. I wanted to know the best way to get all the combos with a grade sum between 100 - 198. the combos can be of any length (i.e {95,1,2,20} and {99,1,53}) and I need to get rid of the repetitions (without {99,2} and {2,99}).

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "permutations of the group of numbers between 1 - 100." Does the order matter--i.e. do you want `[1,99]` stored separately from `[99,1]`? Is repetition allowed--i.e. do you want `[1,1,98]` stored? And you want all *subsets* of the numbers between 1-100 with proper sums?

Comment: I don't think "permutations" is the word you want. A permutation is just a reordering of a set.

Comment: Yes, it is large number. Too large for any conceivable (thinkable?) storage technologies .Do you really need to keep these combinations? Is it possible to generate some partition "when needed"?

Answer (score 0):

I would store them in a 2d-array, simple for sure, but not sure if that's the best route.

Something like this, where the X value in the array gets added to the value:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  ....  98  99 100 
[[ 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 .... 100   0   0 ]
 [   0  99  99  99  99  99  99  99  99 ....  99  99   0 ]
 [   :   :   :   :   :   :   :   :   :        :   :   : ]
 [   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ....   0   0   1]]
```

Another way is you could just put them into a file like this:

```
1   100
2   100
:   100
98  100
2   99
3   99
:   :
100 1
```